# Counting every row by excluding a specific word using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe that looks like the following:

```
id    info_type1    pval1_1    pval2_1     info_type2    pval1_2    pval2_2    info_type3    pval1_3    pval2_3    

ione11    IT       void         0.05       void           1.0       void        IT     void    void    0.04            

ione77    IV       1.0         void       void           1.0       void        void     void    void    0.04
```

For every row, I am trying to count the number of field where it doesn't have the word void. The counting should not include the field id (first field). For example, for the first row, you will have 5 fields that has values other than void and row 2 has 4 values. so I will end up with a list of ids with their values counts. For example:

```
id            count 
ione11         5
ione77         4
```

If I iterate using df.iterrows(), I won't be able to check all the columns per row. How you go about solving this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `apply` on rows:

```py
df_ = pd.DataFrame()

df_['id'] = df['id']
df_['count'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row[1:]) - row[1:].tolist().count('void'), axis=1)
```

To count `void` occurrence in Series, you could also use `sum(row[1:].isin(['void']))`.

```
print(df_)

    id     count
0  ione11      5
1  ione77      4
```

Comment: Nice solution however, when I try printing  df_ , it doesn't include the id only the index which is not the same as the id.

Comment: @aBiologist Did you see my another `print(df_.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'id'}))`?

Comment: Yes tried that. Id is not the index, it is another column in the Dataframe. also, the counting should not count the id column, so the count is not quite right.

Comment: @aBiologist In your example data, first row has 10 values while others have 11 values. Is this right?

Comment: @aBiologist I count for 3 times, they are not the same length. Can you check it again?

Comment: @aBiologist If you are sure they are the same length, check for my update.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is to convert `void` to `NaN` and get a count of all elements that are not `NaNs` using `notna()` and `sum()` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {'ione11': 'IT', 'ione77': 'IV'}, 'info_type1': {'ione11': 'void', 'ione77': '1.0'}, 'pval1_1': {'ione11': '0.05', 'ione77': 'void'}, 'pval2_1': {'ione11': 'void', 'ione77': 'void'}, ' info_type2': {'ione11': 1.0, 'ione77': 1.0}, 'pval1_2': {'ione11': 'void', 'ione77': 'void'}, 'pval2_2': {'ione11': 'IT', 'ione77': 'void'}, 'info_type3': {'ione11': 'void', 'ione77': 'void'}, 'pval1_3': {'ione11': 'void', 'ione77': 'void'}, 'pval2_3': {'ione11': 0.04, 'ione77': 0.04}})
df = df.T.replace({'void' : np.nan}).notna().sum().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count', 'index': 'id'})
df
```

Output:

```
    id      count
0   ione11      5
1   ione77      4
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt but my data is already in a Dataframe and not in a file. You attempt seems that I need to consider reading the data from file.

Comment: No you do not. The dataframe I used looks exactly as yours. Let me edit it with the dataframe I used.

Answer (score 0):

You could map each item to an integer and then sum the rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["it", "void", "1"], ["it", "void", "1"]])        
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == 'void' else 0)
df = df.sum(axis = 1))
```

Resources:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html